# What HiSec Systems in Eve Online are furthest from any LoSec System?

Tags: eve-online

I've seen a discussion and analysis on this site of which Systems give the best/shortest route to most other hisec systems, and I came to wonder which hisec systems are most completely *inaccessible* from any surrounding LoSec (0.4 or lower) systems?

Comment: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/103778/which-high-sec-system-has-the-lowest-average-jump-count-to-all-of-high-sec?newreg=a8ae76636dcd4178911849e679508cc1

Comment: @Iiridayn if you're available, could you take a crack at this?

Comment: I've found a pretty good cul de sac in Croleur System, but I was hoping for a more central area with more connections.